# Location Specification with an iOS MapView

Tags: ios4, geolocation, mkmapview

Using an iOS device, I am interested in tapping a mapview and getting back the lat / long coordinates of that spot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` using `convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView` method of the `MKMapView`.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:[gesture locationInView:self.mapView] toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
```

I put this in a tap gesture handler to work. But if you are using some other mechanism to get the touch point, you can use the touch point as the argument passed in `convertPoint:`.

Comment: @user797678 Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?